# ¿Por que una función en JSON de obtener datos no muestra data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Quisiera que al escribir en una caja de texto se mostraran datos obtenido de una base de datos:

Ya tengo el PHP listo y muestra los datos al colocare un valor de cédula explicito, pero usando el jquery no me funciona.

Tengo un html donde deberían aparecer los valores, usando jquery para llenarlo.

**obtener.PHP**

```
     <?php
session_start();

// CONECTANDO AL SISTEMA SEGUN TIPO DE USUARIO//

if (isset($_SESSION['conectado']) && $_SESSION['conectado'] == true && $_SESSION['nivel'] == 1)
  {

  // --- ENCABEZADO PARA FUNCIONES_PHP ---//

  require_once '__conexion2.php';

  require "funciones/JSON.php";

  $cedula = $_POST["cedula"]; 

  $json = new Services_JSON();

  $stmt = $conexion2->prepare("SELECT xnombre1,xnombre2,xapellido1,xapellido2,cgrado,fult_ascenso FROM pmiperbasd WHERE ccedula=?");
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $cedula);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result();
  if ($stmt->num_rows === 0)
    {
    $datos = $json->encode(array(
      "pnombrex" => '99999'
    ));
    echo $datos;
    }
    else
    {
    $stmt->bind_result($nombre1, $nombre2, $apellido1, $apellido2, $grado, $fult_ascenso);
    $stmt->fetch();
    echo json_encode(array(
        'pnombrex' => $nombre1,
        'snombrex' => $nombre2,
        'papellidox' => $apellido1,
        'sapellidox' => $apellido2,
        'gradox' => $grado,
        'fult_ascenso' => $fult_ascenso
      ));
      }

    // ------------------------ //

    }
    else
    {

    // MENSAJE DE ACCESO NEGADO //

    echo ('<script>alert("No tiene permisos suficientes para acceder a esta parte del sistema");</script>');
    echo ("<script>window.location = 'index.php';</script>");
    exit;

    // ------------------------ //

    }

  // ------------------------ //

  $now = time();
  if ($now > $_SESSION['expira'])
    {

    // DESTRUYO LA SESION, ANTES DE SACARLO DEL SISTEMA//

    session_destroy();

    // MENSAJE DE SESIÓN EXPIRADA //

    echo ('<script>alert("Su sesión ha expirado");</script>');
    echo ("<script>window.location = 'index.php';</script>");
    exit;
    }

  // ------------------------ //

?>
```

**obtener_datosbasicos.js**

```
  function obtenerSancionado() {
var cedula= { cedula: $('#ccedula').val() };
$.get( "funciones_php_obtenerDatosBasicos.php", cedula , function( respuesta ) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(respuesta));
if(respuesta.pnombrex==99999 )
{
   alert("Numero de Cedula no esta Registrado en la Base de Datos");
        $('#ccedula').focus();
        $('#ccedula').val()="";
}
else
{
// ejemplo modificado con el json devuelto
    $('#papellido').val(respuesta.papellidox);
    $('#sapellido').val(respuesta.sapellidox);
    $('#pnombre').val(respuesta.pnombrex);
    $('#snombre').val(respuesta.snombrex);
    $('#grado1').val(respuesta.gradox);
    $('#fascenso').val(respuesta.fult_ascenso);
}   
}, "json" );

}
```

**generar.php**

```
<!-- Librerias -->
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

         <script src="funciones/obtener_datosbasicos.js"></script>



<body onload="refrescado();MostrarFechaA();">
<form id="omd" name="omd" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">


   <tr>
   <td>Cedula: </label></td>
   <td colspan="3">
   <input class="integer" type="text" name="ccedula" id="ccedula" onblur="obtenerSancionado()" maxlength="10" size="12"></td>
   </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
   <td>Nombres: </td>
   <td colspan="3">
   <input class="text" type="text" name="pnombre" id="pnombre"  disabled>
   <input class="text" type="text" name="snombre" id="snombre" disabled>
   </td>
   </tr<>

   <tr>
   <td>Apellidos: </td>
   <td colspan="3">
   <input type="text" name="papellido" id="papellido" onKeyUp="aMays(event, this)" onBlur="aMays(event, this)" disabled>
   <input type="text" name="sapellido" id="sapellido" onKeyUp="aMays(event, this)" onBlur="aMays(event, this)" disabled>
   </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
   <td>Grado/Jerarqu&iacute;a: </td>
   <td colspan="3">
   <input name="grados" type="text" id="grados" size="10" value="" readonly/ disabled> Fecha &Uacute;ltimo Ascenso
   <input name="fascenso" type="text" id="fascenso" size="12" value="" readonly/ disabled>
   <tr>


   <td>Cargo Actual: </td>
   <td colspan="3">
   <input maxlength="40" size="45" type="text" name="cargo" id="cargo" disabled>
   </td>
   </tr>
```

**JS ACTUALIZADO**

```
function obtenerSancionado() {
//se cambiaron las funciones porque habian de javascript con jquery  combinadas, a jquery puro//
$.get("funciones_php_obtenerDatosBasicos", { cedula: $('#ccedula').val() },     verdatos(respuesta), "json"); }

function verdatos(respuesta)
{
if(respuesta.pnombrex==99999 )
{
    alert("Numero de Cedula no esta Registrado en la Base de Datos");
    $('#ccedula').focus();
    $('#ccedula').val()="";
}
else
{
    $('#papellido').val(respuesta.papellidox);
    $('#sapellido').val(respuesta.sapellidox);
    $('#pnombre').val(respuesta.pnombre);
    $('#snombre').val(respuesta.snombre);
    $('#grado').val(respuesta.grado);
}   

}
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55227/discussion-on-question-by-victor-a-obtener-datos-con-json-al-escribir-en-input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya consegui el error, estabamos usando $.get y el valor se obtenia con POST, ese era el problema.

Muchas gracias a **@user2930137** por el formato de obtencion del objeto

Muchisisimas gracias a **@A. Cedano** por corregir el error en el php

Quedo todo ASI:

JS

```
function obtenerSancionado() {
var cedula= { rcedula: $('#ccedula').val() }
$.post("funciones_php_obtenerDatosBasicos.php", cedula , function( respuesta ) {
if(respuesta.pnombrex==99999 )
{
   alert("Numero de Cedula no esta Registrado en la Base de Datos");
        $('#ccedula').focus();
        $('#ccedula').val("");
        throw new FatalError();

}
else
{
// ejemplo modificado con el json devuelto
    $('#papellido').val(respuesta.papellidox);
    $('#sapellido').val(respuesta.sapellidox);
    $('#pnombre').val(respuesta.pnombrex);
    $('#snombre').val(respuesta.snombrex);
    $('#grado1').val(respuesta.gradox);
    $('#fascenso').val(respuesta.fult_ascenso);
    $('#cargo').val(respuesta.cargo);
}   
}, "json" );

}
```

Y el resto como estaba

Answer (score 1):

> Ya tengo el PHP listo y muestra los datos al colocarle un valor de
>   cedula explicitio, pero usando el jquery no me funciona.

He reproducido tu problema usando en el método `$get`de jQuery una url que devuelva valores válidos.

El código funciona perfectamente, como podrás ver más abajo. De modo que tu error no es el jQuery, sino tu PHP, que no está devolviendo los valores esperados.

Creo que es útil mostrar un ejemplo de método GET, tomado de la [misma página oficial](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/):

En este fragmento de código se supone que el archivo `test.php`transmite un arreglo json, algo más o menos así:

**PHP:**

```
<?php 
echo json_encode( array( "name"=>"John","time"=>"2pm" ) ); 
?>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$.get( "test.php", function( data ) {
  $( "body" )
    .append( "Name: " + data.name ) // John
    .append( "Time: " + data.time ); //  2pm
}, "json" );
```

> **EL PROBLEMA**

**Tu PHP no está devolviendo correctamente los resultados esperados.** En SO hay varias respuestas útiles que muestran **cómo consultar a una base de datos desde PHP y devolver el resultado en JSON** o en otro formato.

No se recomienda en SO **hacer una pregunta dentro de otra pregunta**

**PRUEBA DE QUE EL CÓDIGO ORIGINAL FUNCIONA**

Se consulta una URL de prueba que devuelve valores correctos.

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<form id="omd" name="omd" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">


   <tr>
   <td>Cedula: </label></td>
   <td colspan="3">
   <input class="integer" type="text" name="ccedula" id="ccedula" onblur="obtenerSancionado()" maxlength="10" size="12"></td>
   </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
   <td>Nombres: </td>
   <td colspan="3">
   <input class="text" type="text" name="pnombre" id="pnombre"  disabled>
   <input class="text" type="text" name="snombre" id="snombre" disabled>
   </td>
   </tr<>

   <tr>
   <td>Apellidos: </td>
   <td colspan="3">
   <input type="text" name="papellido" id="papellido" onKeyUp="aMays(event, this)" onBlur="aMays(event, this)" disabled>
   <input type="text" name="sapellido" id="sapellido" onKeyUp="aMays(event, this)" onBlur="aMays(event, this)" disabled>
   </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
   <td>Grado/Jerarqu&iacute;a: </td>
   <td colspan="3">
   <input name="grados" type="text" id="grados" size="10" value="" readonly/ disabled> Fecha &Uacute;ltimo Ascenso
   <input name="fascenso" type="text" id="fascenso" size="12" value="" readonly/ disabled>
   <tr>


   <td>Cargo Actual: </td>
   <td colspan="3">
   <input maxlength="40" size="45" type="text" name="cargo" id="cargo" disabled>
   </td>
   </tr>
<script>
function obtenerSancionado() {

$.get("http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two", { cedula: $('#ccedula').val() }, verdatos, "json"); 
}


function verdatos(respuesta)
{
if(respuesta.pnombrex==99999 )
{
    alert("Numero de Cedula no esta Registrado en la Base de Datos");
    $('#ccedula').focus();
    $('#ccedula').get(0).value="";
}
else
{
// ejemplo modificado con el json devuelto
    $('#papellido').val(respuesta.one);
    $('#sapellido').val(respuesta.key);
/*
    $('#pnombre').val(respuesta.pnombre);
    $('#snombre').val(respuesta.snombre);
    $('#grado').val(respuesta.grado)
*/
}   

}
</script>
```

**PRUEBA DEL CÓDIGO DENTRO DEL GET**

Se consulta una URL de prueba que devuelve valores correctos.

```html
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<form id="omd" name="omd" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">


   <tr>
   <td>Cedula: </label></td>
   <td colspan="3">
   <input class="integer" type="text" name="ccedula" id="ccedula" onblur="obtenerSancionado()" maxlength="10" size="12"></td>
   </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
   <td>Nombres: </td>
   <td colspan="3">
   <input class="text" type="text" name="pnombre" id="pnombre"  disabled>
   <input class="text" type="text" name="snombre" id="snombre" disabled>
   </td>
   </tr<>

   <tr>
   <td>Apellidos: </td>
   <td colspan="3">
   <input type="text" name="papellido" id="papellido" onKeyUp="aMays(event, this)" onBlur="aMays(event, this)" disabled>
   <input type="text" name="sapellido" id="sapellido" onKeyUp="aMays(event, this)" onBlur="aMays(event, this)" disabled>
   </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
   <td>Grado/Jerarqu&iacute;a: </td>
   <td colspan="3">
   <input name="grados" type="text" id="grados" size="10" value="" readonly/ disabled> Fecha &Uacute;ltimo Ascenso
   <input name="fascenso" type="text" id="fascenso" size="12" value="" readonly/ disabled>
   <tr>


   <td>Cargo Actual: </td>
   <td colspan="3">
   <input maxlength="40" size="45" type="text" name="cargo" id="cargo" disabled>
   </td>
   </tr>
<script>
function obtenerSancionado() {
var cedula= { cedula: $('#ccedula').val() };

$.get( "http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two", cedula , function( respuesta ) {
if(respuesta.pnombrex==99999 )
{
    alert("Numero de Cedula no esta Registrado en la Base de Datos");
    $('#ccedula').focus();
    $('#ccedula').get(0).value="";
}
else
{
// ejemplo modificado con el json devuelto
    $('#papellido').val(respuesta.one);
    $('#sapellido').val(respuesta.key);
/*
    $('#pnombre').val(respuesta.pnombre);
    $('#snombre').val(respuesta.snombre);
    $('#grado').val(respuesta.grado)
*/
}   
}, "json" );

}
</script>
```

Comment: ya lo tengo asi, ahora no se si el problema esta en el php

Comment: @VictorA. He puesto al final de todo un ejemplo completo funcionando. Lo verás dando al botón Ejecutar. Para que el código funcione tu PHP debe devolver un JSON que contenga los valores que quieres cargar en los input box. En el JSON los valores de la izquierda deben coincidir con los nombres que usaras al hacer `... val(respuesta.pnombre)`, etc. Tu php debe devolver el json haciendo algo parecido a `echo json_encode( array( "pnombre"=>"Pedro","papellido"=>"apellido de pedro" ) );`
`

Comment: @MarcosGallardo No entiendo. **El problema era que estaba llamando mal la función desde ahí**: `$.get("obtener.php", { cedula: $('#ccedula').val() }, ***verdatos****ERROR, "json"); }` fue lo 1º que vi cuando revisé su código.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo La línea estaba así: **`$.get("obtener.php", { cedula: $('#ccedula').val() }, verdatos, "json");`** ¿Crees que así llama a alguien? ¿No ves el error?

Comment: @MarcosGallardo está en lo correcto.

Comment: el ejemplo esta funcional entonces?

Por cierto como podria hacer para usar esa funcion obteniendo lo datos pero para llenar dos registros mas, es decir, dos cedulas mas, tomando en cuenta que los campos del html se llaman diferente

Comment: "Numero de Cedula no esta Registrado en la Base de Datos"

Eso me sale ahora

Comment: @VictorA. Sugiero que investigues del lado de PHP cómo consultar a la base de datos y devolver el resultado en JSON para usarlo en jQuery. Lo que planteas en esta pregunta queda solucionado. Aquí mismo hay preguntas con respuestas que muestran como hacerlo, si no das con la solución entonces vuelves y planteas la dificultad que te pueda estar dando.

Comment: Cierto @MarcosGallardo pregunta editada, fue un error mío de apreciación.

Comment: no creo que responda la pregunta, porque lo unico que se hizo fue acomodar el jquery, cambiando las funciones js, el problema esta en que "no muestra nada", la consulta en php me parece funcional y cuando inserto un valor en el php, me sale todo el string convertido a json.

ahora el programa solo me muestra el error de que no existe la cedula y me borra el campo

Comment: @VictorA. **Tu problema está del lado de PHP** Lo muestran los dos ejemplos de mi respuesta. Y tú decías: _Ya tengo el PHP listo y muestra los datos al colocarle un valor de cedula explicitio, **pero usando el jquery no me funciona.**_ Tu **PHP no estaba listo como decías** La respuesta a **esta** pregunta es que **tu PHP no funciona**, entonces sugiero que investigues como consultar a la BD desde PHP y si no encuentras la solución que vuelvas a preguntar. No puedes hacer una pregunta dentro de otra: _Por cierto como podria hacer para usar esa funcion obteniendo lo datos pero..._

Comment: Ya funciono, la cosa era que el json se mostraba bien tal como le escribe el comentario al user2algo... cuando cambie como tu me decia al fin se paso. por eso te decia que el php estaba consultando bien jejej
muchas gracias :) y disculpa las molestias

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55075/discussion-between-a-cedano-and-victor-a).

Comment: dejo de servir, tenia metido un valor explicito en cedula..

Comment: me disculpo por mi ultimo comentario, me moleste un poco, te equivocas al hablar de las consultas, si observas estas confundiendo bind_param con bind_resulta, te refieres es a la primera, si observas http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php
veras que estan absolutamente bien

/* crear una sentencia preparada */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);

    /* ejecutar la consulta */
    $stmt->execute();
    /* ligar variables de resultado */
    $stmt->bind_result($district);

    /* obtener valor */
    $stmt->fetch();

Comment: ENCONTRE LA SOLUCION, CAMBIE EL GET POR POST xD jajajajaj y sirviio $.get por $.post